# landscape mode in one screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, landscape, portrait

this is my code

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    super.initState();
}

  @override
  dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    super.dispose();
  }
```

the problem is when i push a route to do other things the "dispose" method of current screen doesn't execute which is expected ,and as a result the other screen can be in landscape too
and if i add

```
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
```

in the second screen that fix the problem but when i go back to my main screen it will be portrait only because the "initState" doesn't execute when you pop from second screen

Comment: SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscap,
    ]); in build() method of first widget

Comment: if you pop the second screen the build of the first screen doesn't execute unless you interact with the screen (scroll,press a button ...)

Comment: How you are going to second screen, can you show navigator code?

Comment: regular "pushNamed" , but my goal is to find an easy way to make a specific screen in landscape mode without worrying about  the previous and next screens

Answer (score 0):

Use `WillPopScope`, which will be called on back button press.

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        ]);
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        //we need to return a future
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('screen two'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('other text'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I thought of that but the second screen will be used in many places and not all of them is in landscape

Comment: i'm searching for a function that will be execute one time every time the screen is shown

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/controlling-screen-orientation-in-flutter-apps-on-a-per-screen-basis-d637702f9368